# Mapstruct add annotations in implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I've got entity with `byte[]` field, same as in my DTO object. In both classes those fields are annotated as `@NotNull`. The problem is that mapstruct generate code like that:

```
(@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull :: byte)[] data = file.getData();
```

instead of

```
byte[] data = file.getData()
```

I can use annotation like that

```
@Mapping(ignore = true, source = "data", target = "data")
```

to "solve" this problem, and set those fields in my service, but i don't think it's best solution.

Problem only occurs with this `byte[]`, there is no problem with other `@NonNull` fields.

Comment: How is it a problem? The code that Mapstruct generates is "its own business". Does it cause issues?

Comment: Yes, code does not compile since annotations are not allowed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in MapStruct 1.2.0.Final. It has been fixed since 1.3.0.Beta2 (latest release at the time of this answer).

The reported issue for this was [mapstruct/mapstruct#1558](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1558).

The problem can only be seen when annotations of the type `ElementType.TYPE_VAR` were used for primitive arrays. The same problem can be seen if `int[]` (for example) is used.